# Angular ngx-translate - How to set a default value for missing param in translation value

Tags: html, angular, default, ngx-translate

I wish to have a default value for expected parameter in translation value, in case the programmer doesn't providing one.

For Example, for this key in `en.json`:

```
"NoRecordsWereFound": "No matching {{records}} were found for your search.",
```

In the HTML, when providing the `records` parameters, like here:

```
<span>
    {{('NoRecordsWereFound' | translate:{ records: 'books' })}}
</span>
```

I'll get in the Browser:

**No matching *books* were found for your search.**

But in case of not providing the parameter, like here:

```
<span>
    {{'NoRecordsWereFound' | translate}}
</span>
```

Instead of getting this:
**No matching *{{records}}* were found for your search.**

I'll get some default value for it, like:

**No matching *defaultValue* were found for your search.**

Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ngx-translate default text if key is missing or translation file is being loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662448/ngx-translate-default-text-if-key-is-missing-or-translation-file-is-being-loaded)

Comment: not really, as I understand it helps to switch the whole translation, as I only want to switch one word in it

Answer (score 1):

**Ngx-translate does not provide such a feature, but you have plenty of options in Angular to achive that. Here are some proposals:**

### 1. Use of *ngIf

You can use *ngIf to reference to a different translation:

```
<span *ngIf="books">
    {{('NoRecordsWereFound' | translate:{ records: books })}}
</span>
<span *ngIf="!books">
    {{('NoRecordsWereFound Default' | translate )}}
</span>
```

### 2. Set default value on init or on error state

You can always set a default value on init of the component or if you did some method call, you can set a default value for erroneous responses.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <span>
    {{('NoRecordsWereFound' | translate:{ records: books })}}
   </span>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  books = 'default value';
}
```

You can also use the store to set default states for different scenarios.

Comment: mush appreciate your time and answer, but this is not what I was looking for...
I have the value 'books' anytime, I just want to have a default value in the future for laziness in adding the param.

Comment: I mean, whenever I want to specify what result I didn't get, I will have the 'books' as param... and if I don't want to specify anything, I can be sure I'll get the generic message 'no records found'

Comment: Yeah, you can propose those features to the github repo (altough the repo seems to to be dead now). Other than that you probably need to design around it.

Comment: I mostly use the first method for those things. Also when I display other stuff where I want to show some default values like a message instead of an empty table